# How to return sum value from using group by, having and sum by using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I search many topics relate using Group By and Sum by using LINQ but I cannot use combo between Group By, Having and Sum then return Interger. Can anyone help on this

I have a Datatable

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Name           |     Count        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Apple      |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Apple      |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Orange     |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And I want to return integer about total quantity of apple is 46 by using LINQ (Group By, Having and Sum)

Here is my code but it cannot run

```
 int total = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(tt => tt.Field<string>("Name") == "Apple")
        .GroupBy(tt => tt.Field<string>("Name"))
        .Sum(tt => Int32.Parse(tt.Field<string>("Count")))
```

All code and problem

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Name");
        DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Count");

        dt.Columns.Add(col1);
        dt.Columns.Add(col2);

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[col1] = "Apple";
        row[col2] = 34;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
        row1[col1] = "Apple";
        row1[col2] = 12;
        dt.Rows.Add(row1);

        DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
        row2[col1] = "Orange";
        row2[col2] = 10;
        dt.Rows.Add(row2);

        int total = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(tt => tt.Field<string>("Name") == "Apple")
             .GroupBy(tt => tt.Field<string>("Name"))
             .Sum(tt => Int32.Parse(tt.Field<string>("Count")));
```

Error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1929  'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow, string)' requires a receiver of type 'DataRow'  WindowsFormsApplication1    c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 46  Active

Thanks all,

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour] before you have another downvoted post you feel you need  to delete

Comment: I am so sorry :(

Comment: I try to format the table :(

Comment: The format was not the main problem.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]: this shows no effort

Comment: The topic has data example and my code. I know this is a not a good topic but I believe that I try to my best. Because I only write one or two topic on this forum

Comment: What does "cannot run" mean. Are you getting a compiler error (which one?), a runtime exception (which one?) or just not getting the expected result?

Comment: Is count really a string?

Comment: If I do not use Group By, the code above always return 0. But if the code use Group By, code error at Sum.

Comment: It helps to read the error messages and helps *us* if you tell us what they are.

Comment: I edited the topic

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical problem, which is not the cause the "cannot run". Since you only want to return apples, there no need to group. Simply sum up! If you wanted to return the total count for different products then you would have to group by product.

Then you need to use a type parameter to `Field<T>` that matches the type of the table column. If you have an `int` table column (SQL Server or Numeric Long Access), then you must use `Field<int>`.

```
int total = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Name") == "Apple")
    .Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count"));
```

Note also that in C# the default string comparision mode is case sensitive. So be sure to have the column names and the filter value with the right case.

---

Note also that GroupBy returns a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` and not an `IEnumerable< TSource>`! Therefore you need to work like this:

```
var totals = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Name")
    .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count")));
```

`IGrouping<TKey, TSource>` has a `Key` property and implements an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. Therefore you can apply the `Sum` function on it.

This returns an enumeration of an anonymous type having a `Name` and a `Total` property.

The difference of WHERE and HAVING in SQL is that WHERE is executed before grouping and HAVING after grouping. In LINQ these are always `Where` functions applied either before `GroupBy` or after `GroupBy`. This means that you can have a `Where` as you did, applied on `DataRow`s, before `GroupBy`, or a `Where` after `GroupBy` applied to `IGrouping<string, DataRow>`s. You can even have a `Where` after the `Select` (if you are not using LINQ-to-EF or some other LINQ to Database, i.e. if you are not using an O/R-mapper).

Comment: Did you mean that if return a new datatable I should use Group By, Having and Sum? So could you please give me an example by using Group By, Having and Sum in LINQ?

Comment: BTW, C# being case sensitive has nothing to do with the default string comparison in .NET. The column name doesn't have to match the case, but the column index lookup is faster when it does match.

Comment: I mean the default string comparison mode in C# compared to VBA, for example, where string comparisons are case insensitive by default.

Comment: But it is case sensitive in VB and VBA by default too. AFAIK, string comparison in C# and VB.Net use the same `System.String.Equals(String, String)` method when you check the generated IL.

Comment: Yes, VB.NET; however, VBA is Visual Basic 6.0 for applications and has nothing to do with .NET

Comment: Thanks guys, base on your comments, I have the solution that I will filter the datatable via where and copytodatatable to a new datatable. Then I for each DataRow and Sum them.

Comment: And my code is:

DataTable dtNew = dt.AsEnumerable()
.Where(tt => tt.Field<string>("Name") == "Apple").CopyToDataTable();

int total = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dtNew.Rows)
{
 total += Int32.Parse(dr["Count"].ToString()); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Can be a bit easier if Count is numeric type (otherwise you can use `Convert.ToInt32(r["Count"])`)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");                 // typeof(string) by default
dt.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));   // specify numeric type
dt.Rows.Add("Apple", 34);
dt.Rows.Add("Apple", 12);
dt.Rows.Add("Orange", 10);

// to sum the Count only for Apple:
int AppleCount = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Sum(r => "Apple".Equals(r[0]) ? (int)r[1] : 0); 

// or group by Name if you need the Count of more than one Name
var lookup = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToLookup(r => r[0] as string, r => (int)r[1]);
int iAppleCount = lookup["Apple"].Sum();    // 46
int iOrangeCount = lookup["Orange"].Sum();  // 10

// if Count is numeric tupe, you can also Compute them like this:
var oAppleCount = dt.Compute("Sum(Count)", "Name = 'Apple'"); // 46 (object {long})
```

Comment: so, how to use your code with many conditions such as name is apple, createdate > 2016

Comment: @Kien the answer would depend on too many factors. You can post a separate question with more details on the types, sample input, and expected result

Comment: I think this is the same your solution but I use LINQ to filter

DataTable dtNew = dt.AsEnumerable()
.Where(tt => tt.Field<string>("Name") == "Apple").CopyToDataTable();

int total = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dtNew.Rows)
{
 total += Int32.Parse(dr["Count"].ToString()); 
}

Comment: @Kien Not quite. Your version seems to do a lot of extra unnecessary steps. There is no need to create a new DataTable, you can just add an if statement in the foreach loop. `.Cast`, `.Sum`, and `.ToLookup` are LINQ extensions too.